# Why did the design of the Boeing 247's cockpit windows change for some models?

Tags: aircraft-design, cockpit, windows, boeing-247

Have a look at [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DZ203#United_Airlines) on a famed example of the 247.

The image at the top is the aircraft during its flights with the RAF, likely some time in 1944. Note the reverse-slope windows that are a hallmark of the 247.

Now look at the other aircraft in the same article. They have conventional style slope-down windows. Those two images are from before 1944, one in the 30s and the second around 41/42.

Does anyone know what's going on here? Were certain batches one way or the other?

Comment: I'm certain that something like this has been asked before, well, more about why the reverse-slope was done in the first place.

Comment: @quietflyer [This one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/64804/62)? Not sure it's an exact dupe because this question seems to be about differences within one specific aircraft model.

Comment: Well, the (model specific) answer below looks to be straight out of the answer to that one. VTC as a dupe.

Comment: @quietflyer Ironically, it even has been asked by [the same person](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/64804/why-do-early-airliners-have-backward-slope-windows). And the answer there says what happened: [from the 247D on the window was sloped aft](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25096/what-is-the-purpose-of-eyebrow-windows/25104#25104)

Comment: "By the introduction of the 247D" - This is a question about a D model.

Answer (score 15):

From the [Boeing 247](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_247) article (emphasis mine):

> The cockpit windshield of the first 247s was angled forward, instead of the conventional aft sweep. This was the design solution (similar to that adopted by other contemporary aircraft that used a forward-raked windscreen) to the problem of lighted control panel instruments reflecting off the windshield at night, but **it turned out that the forward-sloping windshield would reflect ground lights instead, especially during landings and it also increased drag slightly**.[13][14] By the introduction of the 247D, the windshield was sloped aft in the usual way, and the night-glare problem was resolved by installing an extension (the glarescreen) over the control panel.[15]

Comment: But this aircraft IS a D model... the mystery deepens.