# Can you identify this scrap cockpit section I found in a scrapyard?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I recently found a scrap cockpit in a scrap yard, and I'm hoping there's enough remaining to identify the aircraft type from pictures.

Unfortunately, all are taken through fencing as I don't have access to the compound.

[Imgur Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvIa0.jpg)

[image: Cockpit Front Close]

[image: Cockpit Rear Close]

[image: Cockpit Front Wide]

[image: Cockpit Rear Wide]

Comment: it reminds me of an A320. Though what such a "new" type would be doing in a scrapyard I don't know.

Comment: Can't be, there's a control yoke column there.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Going by the cockpit glazing, I'd say that's a Hawker Siddeley HS.748:

[image]

Comment: Wow, that looks like a fantastic bet. I'm trying to see if I can find some good cockpit shots but I very much suspect you're correct

Comment: Aaand here we go - positive ID on the little wheel (Rudder trim?) on the back of the center console: https://cdn.airplane-pictures.net/images/uploaded-images/2012/4/18/204161.jpg

Fantastic work, Hobbes!

Comment: The small eyebrow window is a clear hint. +1

Comment: I wonder what the line of thought was behind that eyebrow window's particular shape.  I bet there was a specific reason for it.

Comment: @PeterKämpf What is that window for please?

Comment: My guess regarding the small window - https://live.staticflickr.com/4479/37469435842_8122885bd1_n.jpg ;)

Comment: @Cloud: For observing traffic in a turn. See [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25096/what-is-the-purpose-of-eyebrow-windows) for the same thing on old B737s.