# How do aircraft window size compare to each other? What are some possible improvements on them?

Tags: aircraft-design, windows

I'd like to see a comparison about the window sizes of various commercial aircraft, maybe to give evidence of eventual progress in it over the generations.

For example, I surely know that the B-787 has the biggest ones but it seems strange to me that A350XWB has smaller ones in comparison, considering that it, too, is made with composite materials. Why this difference?

In addition, Boeing increase their window sizes between different iterations of the same model (for example, the first 747s had smaller windows than the later generations, and 777X has larger windows than the original 777), but Airbus seems to not have this approach (neo versions are equal to ceo ones).

Finally, I heard about Boeing Skyview, a very big single windows in Business variants but... is already delivered as solution? Any similar solution from Airbus?

*P.s: I found only a [link with similar topic](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16862/what-are-the-factors-behind-increasing-aircraft-window-sizes) but is more general and not specific to a comparison chart between models and/or difference B787 and A350 construction design related to window size*

Comment: related: [Why were the windows on the Concorde about the size of a hand?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/73031/3394)

Comment: Thank you both. I edit my question. I read also related question noted, but as I wrote for another one, topic is similar but my question is more general

Comment: Passenger windows or cockpit windows?

Comment: Passenger window

Comment: These questions are way too vague.  Basically you have observed that windows are sized differently and you expect someone to write a comparison paper for you, including why design engineers may have selected a particular size for each model aircraft.  You need to narrow the scope and ask a specific question

Comment: Simple flying posted a youtube video on this exact question yesterday: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nc8s98J0hSw
They compare different window sizes on different aircraft and describe some of the reasons for these design decisions.

Comment: Re "Passenger window"-- should be incorporated into question.

Comment: Wouldn't an improvement be not have any windows at all from a structural perspective? Have external cameras and screens instead ;) (only sort of joking here). They are a weak point in a pressurised vessel.

Comment: I specifically pointed on reasons for why B787 and A350XWB, even if both made with same advanced materials are so different in this topic... and in addition why old designed "refreshed" saw great improvements in this aspect if they are Boeing made, for example 777x and why not if made by Airbus, for example A330neo. I think that is not so vague, and in addition answers to these questions are not present in other thread on this site...

Comment: Including the 2 in the title, there are **5** questions here. That, in and of itself, makes this a difficult fit for a Q&A site. There could be 5 very good answers, one for each question - which one do you select as the "correct" or "most useful" answer? This is the SE model - one question, several answers, one selected as "best" (we hope the OP selects one...)

Comment: Older turboprops often had much larger windows (e.g. [Fokker Friendship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker_F27_Friendship#/media/File:Dutch_Air_Force_F-27-300M.jpg)). In this niche, there seem to be a degradation...

Comment: How many airline passengers even look out the windows?  Back in the days when I flew commercial, it seemed that about 99% were glued to the in-flight "entertainment" screens.

Comment: Me!!! :-) Sincerely I hate people that "steals" me window seat and then sleep or read a magazine... Leave me the window seat and sit down on the inner ones... :-)

Answer (score -1):

How aircraft windows compare:

> Aircraft windows can be made bigger by improving the materials of the window or fuselage or reducing the amount of Gs the window frames get by changing the exterior shape and design of the fuselage. Another way is making the window surfaces smoother (to reduce surface friction) or changing the shape of the window itself.